# Cordova windows mobile 10 application build issue

Tags: cordova, build, windows-10-universal

I am trying to make a build for windows 10 mobile app using cordova. 
I am using below command to make a build through CLI command line:

```
cordova build windows --release --buildConfig=platforms/build.json -- --appx=uap --arch=arm
```

But whenever I make build, it gives me below error:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (724,5): error : The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'SQLite3.UWP.vc xproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have
>   specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this
>   project.  Configuration='release'  Platf orm='arm'.  You may be seeing
>   this message because you are trying to build a pr oject without a
>   solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration o r
>   Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
>   [C:\Users\GoleVR\Vishal\aplu-PR
>   \APLU\plugins\cordova-sqlite-storage\src\windows\SQLite3-Win-RT\SQLite3\SQLite3
>   .UWP\SQLite3.UWP.vcxproj] Error: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1

After looking forward, I made below changes. I did change in SQLite3.UWP.vcxproj file by changing version "v141" to "v140".
After doing the version I was able to make a build. But whenever now I am trying to install build to Windows 10 mobile it giving me error as "Failed to start package ******".
Also after doing version change, I saw some changes like it will not create any package for windows mobile 10 cordova application.
Can anyone help me out from this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give some detailed steps for reproducing this problem? like what's inside build.json and can you reproduce this issue on an blank empty project?

Comment: Hi Elvis, Thanks for your reply. I resolved the issue by updating my windows platform version through CLI command line with changing version in SQLite file from "v141" to "v140". Now it's working fine.